# Api sdk or database for simulating a turing test?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to provide a chat like environment game for kids to detect if the person speaking to them is human or not (similar to what Eugene did).

I'm looking for an SDK or api that would provide me with replies for sentences (either with context of the entire conversation or without). An alternative would be a an entire database of sentences that I'll be able to search for myself and implement my own logic.

Another option is to integrate some kind of open source solution if possible.

Does anyone know of such a service \ solution can could point me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 2):

If you want some database of discusions then try to found some Corpus of dialogs this is the first one which i found. It is the corpus of movie dialogs:

http://www.mpi-sws.org/~cristian/Cornell_Movie-Dialogs_Corpus.html

And if you want some chat-bot to use in your program than is probably easiest way to use some public available api of one. There is again something which could work for you:

http://blog.program-o.com/chatbot-api/

Good Luck